# What is the purpose of the comma in this C macro?

Tags: c

I saw something similar to this in [stretchy_buffer.h](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stretchy_buffer.h):

```
#define stb_sb_free(a) ((a) ? free(stb__sbraw(a)),0 : 0)
```

What is the purpose of the `,0` after the call to `free()`?

Similarly, there are two curious commas here:

```
#define stb_sb_add(a,n) (stb__sbmaybegrow(a,n), stb__sbn(a)+=(n), &(a)[stb__sbn(a)-(n)])
```

It seems like it's running multiple statements, but wouldn't that require a semicolon?

Comment: Comma operator? All expressions are evaluated.

Comment: Since free doesn't return a value, the comma operator means that the expression evaluates to zero regardless of the condition being true or false.

Comment: The conditional operator has to have both operands the same type (or implicitly convertible) , you can't have one branch yield `void` and the other branch yield `int`

Comment: Seems like obfuscation. `free()` can handle a null pointer. Maybe `stb__sbraw` can't, but then the solution would be to rewrite that function.

Comment: The comma operator returns the value of the right operand, so it is used in these (evil) macros to emulate a function call with a certain, expected return value. Basically those macros are "wrappers" around some function calls and whoever wrote them want them to behave like macros. But the second macro doesn't make any sense at all, it is full of statements with no obvious side-effects. So perhaps the person who wrote the code simply did not have a clue about what they were doing. The _correct_ solution is of course to write an actual wrapper function, which will get inlined.

Comment: @Lundin I deleted my extraneous discussion comments because they added no value to the question. This comment will self-destruct in 1 hour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens in this line

```
#define stb_sb_free(a) ((a) ? free(stb__sbraw(a)),0 : 0)
```

is, if `a` corrsponseds to `true`, first `free(stb__sbraw(a))` will be executed, then `0` will be returned due to `,0`.

In general, all expressions which they're separated by comma will be evaluated, but the result has the type and value of the rightmost expression.